# CordovaLib:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac FAILED - ionic build failing for Android TargetSDK 33

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic2

To upload my Android App to the Google Play Developer Console, I was informed that a Target SDK of 33 is required.

`<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="33"/>`

I had this setting in the config.xml and built my App through Ionic AppFlow and got this error.

[image]

Please help!

Comment: Update your Java version to 17.

Comment: Thanks. It worked with Java version 11.